# How To Expose Google Analytics Realtime Active Users To Public

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, long-polling

I want to embed real-time Google Analytics active users number within my web app

Here how it looks on Google Analytics dashboard -the number changes real-time with actual active users now-:

[image]

What I need is to put this number on my web app.

But the API is a bit weird: it gives "you" (with google account authorization) just this access

```js
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
  /**
   * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
   * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
   * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: '1061030166084-94nlg92ep9aejnepvggfr72pkg4h2lnc.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  });
  /**
   * Create a new ActiveUsers instance to be rendered inside of an
   * element with the id "active-users-container" and poll for changes every
   * five seconds.
   */
  var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
    container: 'active-users-container',
    pollingInterval: 5
  });
});
```

So how can I expose this real-time number to "public" as an app download promotion

Answer (score 1):

> "public" as an app download promotion

I am not sure I understand what you mean by download promotion.

However here are a few things you should be aware of. There is a  limit to the number of requests you can send to this API per day per view.  That limit being 10000 requests per day.  This quota limit is across the view across all applications so if the user has your web app installed looking at their real time data and they have mine installed looking at their Google Analytics data we are sharing the 10000 requests.   If you do this you are going to quickly blow out the quota for your users.   In which case they wont be able to request anymore data for the rest of the day.

Assuming that you are only displaying the real-time google analytics data for your own web site.  What you should be doing is having a service run in the background that runs every five minutes or something and gets the current count then you can display this stored count to all your users rather than making requests for each of your users.

You may want to consider doing this using a service account as you wont have to worry about authentication then.   Note: Service accounts dont work with JavaScript you will need to use a server sided language for this.

Comment: Thanks, @DalmTo, so you suggest making my own server implementation for this purpose and not relying on Google quota limit? will socket.io will be a good way of doing that or that will be resources costly?

Comment: This is how i have done it in the past i had a php script running in a cron job its up to you how you do it really.    Look into service accounts if this is your own account you are showing data for.

Comment: @DalmTo I mean by public that anyone visiting my app or website can view it without special auth, it's an Android and iOS app

Comment: Yes but its your Google Analytics account.   You can use a service account to extract the data rather than using Oauth2 which requires you to authenticate the script at least once.   You may find this interesting http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/